# Simple way to bind radiobuttons to SQL table in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm trying to bind an SQL table to radio buttons in a Windows Forms application.

The buttons are grouped by group boxes. I haven't yet find a way to bind them correctly to the datasource. I know some had managed to do this by creating a custom control, but is there a simpler way?

Comment: What are you trying to bind the radiobuttons to? Multiple boolean columns in the table per groupbox?

Comment: What database access technology do you want to use? ADO.NET? LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework?

Comment: Are the values of the buttons tied to an enumeration or 1 column in your table or are the answers supported in a series of columns?

Comment: A button pair is tied to a column in a MySQL table which either be enabled or disabled depending on the value 1 or 0.

Comment: Enabled or disabled calls for check box instead of two radio buttons.

Comment: I know. That was my first thought too but the users some reason prefer radiobuttons. So here is the challenge. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: This is probably a cleaner way to do it (untested, but should work).

You should actually bind directly (using a `Binding`) to the radiobuttons, but handle the [`Binding.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse.aspx) and [`Binding.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx) events.

In the 'Format' event, set the Checked properties and in the `Parse` event, you'll save the value back based on which one is checked.

---

Original Idea: Without creating a custom control or subclassing, the simplest way is probably not to bind directly but to load and save the values yourself as an intermediary.

One way is:

- Subscribe to the  [`BindingSource.CurrentItemChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.currentitemchanged.aspx) event and set the radiobutton `Checked` properties accordingly.
- Subscribe to the `RadioButton.CheckedChanged` events and set the underlying data source appropriately.

Comment: This is a far better solution than mine!, you have to remember the name of those events of course, but it's elegant +1

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks! - I would give +1 but I have no credentials yet ;)

Comment: Sounds even better! Thanks very much.

Comment: No I do. :) so here you go +1. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. After getting my head around it, it did. :) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a dirty trick:

Create a hidden textbox. Bind it to the datasource, and leave the radio buttons unbound. Then program the textbox change event to set the radio buttons value and the radio button click events to set the text bot value.

Dirty, but it works.